# lwuit exception on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, netbeans, lwuit

"uncaught exception thrown in midlet constructor: userclasses.MainMIDlet" while trying to run lwuit application on blackberry mobile device. I am developing with netbeans+lwuit+resource editor.

Comment: problem like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083348/the-app-dont-start-in-blackberry-device-lwuit

Comment: @frayab yes, it's thesame issue but everything works fine on the emulator for me, even network connection works fine on emulator. but unfortunately there was no answer on the post you directed me. I home someone would have an answer for me.
 thank you

Comment: @Chilbex, everything works fine in my simulator. It's in the device where is not working. Is the same issue.

Comment: @jmunoz, it's just occurred to me now, it's like we are following the wrong path. the simulator deployed .cod file while testing on it, but I was deploying .jar file on my friends blackberry. it's late in the night in my country now, by tomorrow morning I will install .cod file on their device instead and see what happens.

Comment: I install the .alx file in my blackberry and doesn't work (.alx  is used within 'BlackBerry Desktop Manager' and communicates the location of the application on your computer to be installed) I will try with jar tomorrow, but I have little hope

Comment: Did you see my question? @ShaiAlmog answered it!

Answer (score 1):

My issue was .cod file. from the solutions I got online, I had to extract .cod siblings from the main .cod file generated and copied them with .jad that contains their name reference into thesame folder on the device. after I ran the jad file and it installed cod files. and the application is working fine now.

Comment: This is actually what I do when I want to test on a Blackberry device. I wonder what will happen when its time to officially deploy the app :(

Comment: from my sources, when it comes to deployment for example to your webserver you should still copy the individual COD files with associated JAD file to thesame folder on your webserver. then provide the like the JAD file to your users. because jad file contains the cod files names, they will be downloaded as a single download. I have not tried it thou, because my app for blackberry is not yet ready.

Comment: That is the logical way to do it @chibex, but what happens when you want to upload to app stores like getjar? I had no choice but to upload the original single COD sometime back, because they only allowed a single COD then a JAD file. Unless they have changed, this is bothersome, as some users may encounter our issues when downloading as well.